# GV650 4CH Drivers for monitor

Tags: 16.04, video-capture-card

This is my first project with the Linux operating system. I'm trying to build a surveillance system, I have a PC with GV650 4CH BNC, and I'm stuck at the point of adding monitors. It's not showing anything except a broken image link. The system is showing me `/dev/video0` and `/dev/video1`, however, I'm assuming that Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't have the driver for GV650. Any advice on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if this is still relevant > https://forums.zoneminder.com/viewtopic.php?t=21897#p83184 (re: 12.04 and the poster complains about other issue; the settings may help you though).

Comment: Thanks for replay, the setting for working camera, i'm unable to see any picture yet. still looking for gv650 driver, is there anyway to compile and add the driver